# What CMS for parenting purpose?

Tags: newborn, sharing, social-media

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Kids Website, is it a good idea?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/6060/kids-website-is-it-a-good-idea)

I'm about to be a mother soon (yay) and I would like to share with people my new mom's experience. I'm not a big fan of social networks so I think blog is a good way to do this, not only with my family but with anyone that could help.

Now I need to go for a CMS and I really don't know what to choose between Wordpress, Joomla, Drupal, etc. 
I'm looking for something easy and looking nice (skins). Any idea?

Comment: I wish you all the best for the interesting weeks and years that will come. Sorry, this is not an answer to your question, but in my opinion it is important to also respect the privacy of the baby. Things that have been published on the internet once might rest there (or at least "somewhere else") forever.  Is this really a good idea?

Comment: Hello Lea, and welcome to the site!! As it stands, your question is not actually about _parenting_ but rather about _computer software._ Your question is more likely to get good responses on an IT website (try [Superuser.com](http://Superuser.com) or maybe [the WordPress Stack Exchange site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com)). I linked it to an existing question that addresses the parenting considerations about having a website. That might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I've found http://wordpress.com to be a decent platform to use.  Having your blog hosted is really nice because you do not have to think about hosting, security, updates, etc...  I pay them for my own domain name (a few dollars per year).

**Here is an example:  http://blog.gahooa.com**

By starting with your own domain name, you are not "locking yourself in" to a particular provider (although, moving isn't easy).

I cannot speak for the others, other than I chose hosted wordpress after looking at the others.  I wanted to spend as little time learning/messing around as possible, and more time just posting.